# How to add separate view dynamically to a scrollview or a listview?

Tags: android, listview

I have a layout and multiple rows(multiple xml files) containing either a checkbox or two textview's or one image or a single textview.
I call a service and in return i get a json containing the type of layout i want to add in the currect layout file .For example :-

```
{
    "data": {
        "layouts": [
            {
                "id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 3
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now there are three id's so i will have toinflate three different layouts xml files beneath each other and all of them are different.

Also there is a button to add a view beneath the other inflated views.
So any suggestions please as to how to achieve this

Comment: Its not about creating view dynamically "Textview t = new TextView() and so on". Its about multiple xml files to be added on the basis of json.

Comment: switch case id and inflate wanted layout based on id.

Comment: Add a view to ScrollView: simply add it to the ViewGroup the ScrollView contains. Adding a view to a ListView is harder, you need to add the data to the Adapter and refresh the listview/adapter. So what is the "hard" part you are struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually inflate the same thing multiple times, and piece it together. For instance, I have done things like this before. If you follow this principal in what you are trying to do, it should help you.

```
String[] values=new String[]{"Value 1","Value 2","Value 3"};
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) li.inflate(R.layout.some_linear_layout);
for (String value:values) {
    TextView tv=(TextView) li.inflate(R.layout.some_text_view);
    tv.setText(value);
    ll.addView(tv);
}
```

If you want to change the view based off of some ID number, just do a switch statement to determine what type of view you want to do, something like this:

```
View view;
int id=json.getInt("id");
swtich (id) {
case 0:
    view=li.inflate(R.layout.view_1);
    break;
case 1:
    view=li.inflate(R.layout.view_2);
    break;
}
li.addView(view);
```